# Why Is My Genetic Algorithm Terrible (Why Doesn't It Converge)?

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I wrote a quick experiment with a genetic algorithm. It simply takes a grid of squares and tries to mutate their color to make them all yellow. It fails miserably and I can't seem to figure out why. I've included a link to JSFiddle that demonstrates working code, as well as a copy of the code in its entirety.

http://jsfiddle.net/mankyd/X6x9L/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>The randomly flashing squares <i>should</i> be turning yellow</h1>
            <div class="row">
                <canvas id="input_canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
                <canvas id="output_canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <span id="generation"></span>
                <span id="best_fitness"></span>
                <span id="avg_fitness"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that the below javascript relies on jquery in a few places.

```
// A bit of code that draws several squares in a canvas
// and then attempts to use a genetic algorithm to slowly
// make those squares all yellow.

// Knobs that can be tweaked
var mutation_rate = 0.1; // how often should we mutate something
var crossover_rate = 0.6; // how often should we crossover two parents
var fitness_influence = 1; // affects the fitness's influence over mutation
var elitism = 1; // how many of the parent's generation to carry over
var num_offspring = 20; // how many spawn's per generation
var use_rank_selection = true; // false == roulette_selection

// Global variables for easy tracking
var children = []; // current generation
var best_spawn = null; // keeps track of our best so far
var best_fitness = null; // keeps track of our best so far
var generation = 0; // global generation counter
var clear_color = 'rgb(0,0,0)';

// used for output
var $gen_span = $('#generation');
var $best_fit = $('#best_fitness');
var $avg_fit = $('#avg_fitness');
var $input_canvas = $('#input_canvas');
var input_ctx = $input_canvas[0].getContext('2d');
var $output_canvas = $('#output_canvas');
var output_ctx = $output_canvas[0].getContext('2d');

// A spawn represents a genome - a collection of colored
// squares.
var Spawn = function(nodes) {
    var _fitness = null; // a cache of our fitness
    this.nodes = nodes; // the squares that make up our image

    this.fitness = function() {
        // fitness is simply a function of how close to yellow we are.
        // This is defined through euclidian distance. Smaller fitnesses
        // are better.

        if (_fitness === null) {
            _fitness = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                _fitness += Math.pow(-nodes[i].color[0], 2) + 
                            Math.pow(255 - nodes[i].color[1], 2) +
                            Math.pow(255 - nodes[i].color[2], 2);
            }
            _fitness /= 255*255*3*nodes.length; // divide by the worst possible distance
        }

        return _fitness;
    };

    this.mutate = function() {
        // reset our cached fitness to unknown
        _fitness = null;

        var health = this.fitness() * fitness_influence;
        var width = $output_canvas[0].width;
        var height = $output_canvas[0].height;

        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            // Sometimes (most times) we don't mutate
            if (Math.random() > mutation_rate) {
                continue;
            }

            // Mutate the colors. 
            for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                // colors can move by up to 32 in either direction
                nodes[i].color[j] += 64 * (.5 - Math.random()) * health;
                // make sure that our colors stay between 0 and 255
                nodes[i].color[j] = Math.max(0, Math.min(255, nodes[i].color[j]));
            }
        }
    };

    this.draw = function(ctx) {
        // This draw function is a little overly generic in that it supports
        // arbitrary polygons.
        ctx.save();
        ctx.fillStyle = clear_color;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + Math.floor(nodes[i].color[0]) + ',' + Math.floor(nodes[i].color[1]) + ',' + Math.floor(nodes[i].color[2]) + ',' + nodes[i].color[3] + ')';
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(nodes[i].points[0][0], nodes[i].points[0][1]);
            for (var j = 1; j < nodes[i].points.length; j++) {
                ctx.lineTo(nodes[i].points[j][0], nodes[i].points[j][1]);
            }
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
        }
        ctx.restore();
    };
};

Spawn.from_parents = function(parents) {
    // Given two parents, mix them together to get another spawn
    var nodes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < parents[0].nodes.length; i++) {
        if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
            nodes.push($.extend({}, parents[0].nodes[i]));
        }
        else {
            nodes.push($.extend({}, parents[1].nodes[i]));
        }
    }
    var s = new Spawn(nodes);
    s.mutate();

    return s;
};

Spawn.random = function(width, height) {
    // Return a complete random spawn.
    var nodes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < width * height; i += 10) {
        var n = {
            color: [Math.random() * 256, Math.random() * 256, Math.random() * 256, 1],
            points: [
                [i % width, Math.floor(i / width) * 10],
                [(i % width) + 10, Math.floor(i / width) * 10],
                [(i % width) + 10, Math.floor(i / width + 1) * 10],
                [i % width, Math.floor(i / width + 1) * 10],
                ]
        };
        nodes.push(n);
    }
    return new Spawn(nodes);
};

var select_parents = function(gene_pool) {
    if (use_rank_selection) {
        return rank_selection(gene_pool);
    }
    return roulette_selection(gene_pool);
};

var roulette_selection = function(gene_pool) {
    var mother = null;
    var father = null;
    gene_pool = gene_pool.slice(0);
    var sum_fitness = 0;
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < gene_pool.length; i++) {
        sum_fitness += gene_pool[i].fitness();
    }
    var choose = Math.floor(Math.random() * sum_fitness);
    for (i = 0; i < gene_pool.length; i++) {
        if (choose <= gene_pool[i].fitness()) {
            mother = gene_pool[i];
            break;
        }
        choose -= gene_pool[i].fitness();
    }
    // now remove the mother and repeat for the father
    sum_fitness -= mother.fitness();
    gene_pool.splice(i, 1);
    choose = Math.floor(Math.random() * sum_fitness);
    for (i = 0; i < gene_pool.length; i++) {
        if (choose <= gene_pool[i].fitness()) {
            father = gene_pool[i];
            break;
        }
        choose -= gene_pool[i].fitness();
    }
    return [mother, father];
};

var rank_selection = function(gene_pool) {
    gene_pool = gene_pool.slice(0);
    gene_pool.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.fitness() - a.fitness();
    });

    var choose_one = function() {
        var sum_fitness = (gene_pool.length + 1) * (gene_pool.length / 2);
        var choose = Math.floor(Math.random() * sum_fitness);
        for (var i = 0; i < gene_pool.length; i++) {
            // figure out the sume of the records up to this point. if we exceed
            // our chosen spot, we've found our spawn.
            if ((i + 1) * (i / 2) >= choose) {
                return gene_pool.splice(i, 1)[0];
            }
        }

        return gene_pool.pop(); // last element, if for some reason we get here
    };

    var mother = choose_one();
    var father = choose_one();
    return [mother, father];
};

var start = function() {
    // Initialize our first generation
    var width = $output_canvas[0].width;
    var height = $output_canvas[0].height;

    generation = 0;
    children = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < num_offspring; j++) {
        children.push(Spawn.random(width, height));
    }

    // sort by fitness so that our best comes first
    children.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.fitness() - b.fitness();
    });
    best_spawn = children[0];
    best_fitness = best_spawn.fitness();
    best_spawn.draw(output_ctx);
};

var generate = function(spawn_pool) {
    // generate a new set of offspring
    var offspring = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < num_offspring; i++) {
        var parents = select_parents(spawn_pool);
        // odds of crossover decrease as we get closer
        if (Math.random() * best_fitness < crossover_rate) {
            var s = Spawn.from_parents(parents);
        }
        else {
            // quick hack to copy our mother, with possible mutation
            var s = Spawn.from_parents([parents[0], parents[0]]);
        }
        offspring.push(s);
    }
    // select a number of best from the parent pool (elitism)
    for (var i = 0; i < elitism; i++) {
        offspring.push(spawn_pool[i]);
    }

    // sort our offspring by fitness (this includes the parents from elitism). Fittest first.
    offspring.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.fitness() - b.fitness();
    });
    // pick off the number that we want
    offspring = offspring.slice(0, num_offspring);
    best_spawn = offspring[0];
    best_fitness = best_spawn.fitness();
    best_spawn.draw(output_ctx);
    generation++;

    return offspring;
};


var average_fitness = function(generation) {
    debugger;
    var a = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < generation.length; i++) {
        a += generation[i].fitness();
    }
    return a / generation.length;
};

//Draw yellow and then initialize our first generation
input_ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
input_ctx.fillRect(0, 0, input_ctx.canvas.width, input_ctx.canvas.height);
start();

// Our loop function. Use setTimeout to prevent things from freezing
var gen = function() {
    children = generate(children);
    $gen_span.text('Generation: ' + generation);
    $best_fit.text('Best Fitness: ' + best_fitness);
    $avg_fit.text('Avg. Fitness: ' + average_fitness(children));
    if (generation % 100 === 0) {
        console.log('Generation', generation);
        console.log('Fitness', best_fitness);
    }
    setTimeout(gen, 1);
};
gen();​
```

I've commented the code to try to make parsing it easy. The basic idea is quite simple:

1. Select 1 or 2 parents from the current generation
2. Mix those one or two parents together
3. Mutate the result slightly and add it to the next generation
4. Select the best few parents (1 in the example) and add them to the next generation
5. Sort and slice off N results and use them for the next generation (potentially a mix of parents and offspring)
6. Rinse and repeat

The output never gets anywhere near yellow. It quickly falls into a steady state of a sort that looks awful. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. It was in the "from_parents" method:

```
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        nodes.push($.extend({}, parents[0].nodes[i]));
    }
    else {
        nodes.push($.extend({}, parents[1].nodes[i]));
    }
```

The `$.extend()` was doing a shallow copy. The obvious solution was to either put `true` as the first argument which causes a deep copy. This, however, is incredibly slow performance-wise. The better solution was to remove the `$.extend()` from that chunk of code entirely and instead to move it up to the `mutate()` method, where I call `$.extend()` only if a node is actually about to be changed. In other words, it becomes a copy-on-write.

Also, the color I put in the fitness function was wrong :P

Comment: Hi, can you update your jsfiddle with your solved solution, I am curious to see how all squares emerge to yellow. Thanks.

Comment: @csg here is a version that works: http://jsfiddle.net/mankyd/X6x9L/9/  The closer fitness is to 0, the better. You'll really start to see the yellow come through around .1 to .15. I actually have a much more impressive demo that I am working on that I should have ready in the next few days. I'll keep you posted!